# Sublime Text 3, LaTeX Tools, and compiling with LuaLaTeX via %!TEX program = lualatex not working

Tags: sublime-text-3, latex, sublime-text

I'm using Sublime Text 3 with the LaTeX Tools package, and need to compile a .tex document with LuaLaTeX (in order to use the tikz graph drawing library).  I put `%!TEX program = lualatex` as the very first thing in my file, but the build command results in `Basic Builder: running pdflatex...done.` and a flood of errors.  The document compiles without errors using `lualatex` from the command line.  I presume that Sublime Text is not recognizing / implementing my `%!TEX` command.  Is there a fix?

Comment: I have the exact problem... @kyle-o did you manage to solve it?